# Elastic Search - normal query worked but fuzzy_like_this didn't work (with function_score)

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

What I am trying to do is just getting the score from fuzzy_like_this query for further processing. It doesn't work but normal query works.

This worked,

```
POST /merchantindex/_search
{
    "query": {
      "function_score" : {
         "query" :{
            "query_string": { "query": "tes"}
         },
         "functions": [
         {
            "script_score": {
                "script": "return _score/log(1.1 + sqrt(pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[0] - _source.loc.coordinates[0],2)+pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[1] - _source.loc.coordinates[1],2)));"
            }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

But this didn't work,

```
POST /merchantindex/_search
{
    "query": {
      "function_score" : {
         "query" :{
            "fuzzy_like_this" : {
        "fields" : ["title", "desc", "loc.locNm", "category", "subCategoryList.subCategory"],
        "like_text" : "tes",
        "max_query_terms" : 12
    }
         },
         "functions": [
         {
            "script_score": {
                "script": "return _score/log(1.1 + sqrt(pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[0] - _source.loc.coordinates[0],2)+pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[1] - _source.loc.coordinates[1],2)));"
            }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

Error that I got is

```
{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[H94j5eYQRXantctqOKMduw][merchantindex][0]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[merchantindex][0]: query[function score (null,function=script[return _score/log(1.1 + sqrt(pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[0] - _source.loc.coordinates[0],2)+pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[1] - _source.loc.coordinates[1],2)));], params [null])],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[NullPointerException[null]]; }{[H94j5eYQRXantctqOKMduw][merchantindex][1]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[merchantindex][1]: query[function score (null,function=script[return _score/log(1.1 + sqrt(pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[0] - _source.loc.coordinates[0],2)+pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[1] - _source.loc.coordinates[1],2)));], params [null])],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[NullPointerException[null]]; }{[H94j5eYQRXantctqOKMduw][merchantindex][2]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[merchantindex][2]: query[function score (null,function=script[return _score/log(1.1 + sqrt(pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[0] - _source.loc.coordinates[0],2)+pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[1] - _source.loc.coordinates[1],2)));], params [null])],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[NullPointerException[null]]; }{[H94j5eYQRXantctqOKMduw][merchantindex][3]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[merchantindex][3]: query[function score (null,function=script[return _score/log(1.1 + sqrt(pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[0] - _source.loc.coordinates[0],2)+pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[1] - _source.loc.coordinates[1],2)));], params [null])],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[NullPointerException[null]]; }{[H94j5eYQRXantctqOKMduw][merchantindex][4]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[merchantindex][4]: query[function score (null,function=script[return _score/log(1.1 + sqrt(pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[0] - _source.loc.coordinates[0],2)+pow(_source.userLoc.coordinates[1] - _source.loc.coordinates[1],2)));], params [null])],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[NullPointerException[null]]; }]",
   "status": 500
}
```

Enlighten me please senpai!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. For the script scoring, remember to check for null values. If null then maybe replace the value with 1.